# Where to put Play package for console to recognize command?

Tags: scala, playframework, installation

Download binary packages on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Installing gives me a play-2.0 folder with play exec file. However running play on that same directory using console returns

```
play: command not found
```

My environment is MAC and I tried

```
chmod a+x play
```

while running into the same problem

Can someone give me a guide on the installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we run a `command`, the shell look for this file (`command`) in a list of directories (folders). This list of directories is stored in a enviroment variable called `PATH`. If you want to see the values inside `PATH`. You can run:

```
echo $PATH
```

Note that the folders are separated by `:`.

The problem you are facing is because the shell can't find a dir that contains the file `play`. This happens because the play's dir is not in `PATH`

You can add play's dir to your `PATH` by running

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/play/dir
```

This is a temporary thing. After you exit your shell session you will loose it. To make it permanent you need to edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home folder and add this command in the end of the file and save it.

Comment: When I execute `play help` I am in the directory where play exec file exist

Comment: What is the directory play is installed? You can get this with the command `pwd`. Can you update the answer with this?

Comment: Updated answer explaining that doesn't doesn't matter where you are shell always look for executables in PATH, no current dir